# \ShortStack Align

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

`Some sentence.... \shortstack[]{a\\b\\c}` it produces like

> ```
>                   a
>                   b
> Some sentence.... c
> ```

But I would like to produce something like this

> ```
>                       a
> Some Sentence...      b
>                       c
> ```

I want to align the "Some sentence....." with be instead of c.

Comment: Could it be that you would like to get the sentence and the stack vertically centered to each other? Aligning to b would mean that the stack, as it is, won't be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix perhaps:

```
Some sentence.... $\matrix{ a \cr b \cr c }$
\bye
```

Comment: Package amsmath Error: Old form `\matrix' should be \begin{matrix}.
See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.            
l.745 Some sentence.... $\matrix{ a \cr b \cr c }$ When I put in a matrix this is the error I get ----  Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.745 Some sentence.... \begin{matrix}
                                      $\matrix{ a \cr b \cr c }$\end{matrix}
?

Comment: @Aku: use `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}` within `$...$`, not outside math mode, then morbusg's suggestion works. (Without amsmath it works in original syntax.)

Comment: $\begin{matrix}\matrix{ a \cr b \cr c } \end{matrix}$

This is the error I got 

Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>  }
l.768 $\begin{matrix}\matrix{ a \cr
                                    b \cr c }

Comment: @Aku: You want `Some sentence.... $\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix}$`.  (It works like all the other environments, pairing a `\begin{envname}` with and `\end{envname}`.)